# Sorting rows by the number of list elements the row contains

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, timeit

Taking as example the following table:

| index | column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | bli bli | d e |
| 1 | bla bla | a b c d e |
| 2 | ble ble | a b c |

If I give a `token_list = ['c', 'e']` I want to order the table by the number of times the tokens each row contains in column number 2.

By ordering the table I should get the following:

| index | column_1 | column_2 | score_tmp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bla bla | a b **c** d **e** | 2 |
| 0 | bli bli | d **e** | 1 |
| 2 | ble ble | a b **c** | 1 |

Currently, I have reached the following way of doing this, but it is taking a lot of time. How could I improve the time? Thank you in advance.

```py
df['score_tmp'] = df[['column_2']].apply(
            lambda x: len([True for token in token_list if
            token in str(x['column_2'])]), axis=1)
results = df.sort_values('score_tmp', ascending=False).loc[df['score_tmp'] == len(token_list)].reset_index(inplace=False).to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` column_2 based on whitespaces, convert each row into a `set` and then use  [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`set intersection`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp) with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
In [200]: df['matches'] = df.column_2.str.split().apply(lambda x: set(x) & set(token_list)).str.len()

In [204]: df.sort_values('matches', ascending=False).drop('matches', 1)
Out[204]: 
   index column_1   column_2
1      1  bla bla  a b c d e
0      0  bli bli        d e
2      2  ble ble      a b c
```

**Timings**:

```
In [208]: def f1():
     ...:     df['score_tmp'] = df[['column_2']].apply(lambda x: len([True for token in token_list if token in str(x['column_2'])]), axis=1)
     ...:     results = df.sort_values('score_tmp', ascending=False).loc[df['score_tmp'] == len(token_list)].reset_index(inplace=False).to_dict('records')
     ...: 

In [209]: def f2():
     ...:     df['matches'] = df.column_2.str.split().apply(lambda x: set(x) & set(token_list)).str.len()
     ...:     df.sort_values('matches', ascending=False).drop('matches', 1)
     ...: 

In [210]: %timeit f1() # solution provided in question
2.36 ms ± 55.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [211]: %timeit f2() # my solution
1.22 ms ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `str.count()`

```
df.sort_values('column_2',
               key = lambda x: x.str.count('|'.join(token_list)),
               ascending=False)
```

Using the `key` parameter of `sort_values()`, we do not have to make a temporary column to do the sorting.

Output:

```
   index column_1   column_2
1      1  bla bla  a b c d e
0      0  bli bli        d e
2      2  ble ble      a b c
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.assign(
     score_tmp =
     [len(np.intersect1d(x,token_list)) for x in df['column_2'].str.split(' ')])
 .sort_values('score_tmp', ascending=False))
```

Output:

```
  column_1   column_2  score_tmp
1  bla bla  a b c d e          2
0  bli bli        d e          1
2  ble ble      a b c          1
```